# AADSTS50034: The user account Microsoft.AzureAD.Telemetry.Diagnostics.PII does not exist in the xxx.onmicrosoft.com directory

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to use graph.microsft.com apis for user invinting to the AD account.
I was able to invite but when try to get the token using
https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token i am getting the above error.
I am using this key along with other required keys in the header.
[{"key":"resource","value":"https://graph.microsoft.com","description":""}]

Can you please let me know what is the issue?
Complete log.

{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "AADSTS50034: The user account Microsoft.AzureAD.Telemetry.Diagnostics.PII does not exist in the xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com directory. To sign into this application, the account must be added to the directory.\r\nTrace ID: 5537uiy4b-4473-4cfb-b45c-1281f61e2100\r\nCorrelation ID: 8121era7-8df4-47d5-8cc5-3d2f8371029b0\r\nTimestamp: 2019-02-26 11:04:46Z",
    "error_codes": [
        50034
    ],
    "timestamp": "2019-02-26 11:04:46Z",
    "trace_id": "5537db4b-4473-4cfb-b45c-1281f61e2100",
    "correlation_id": "812138a7-8df4-47d5-8cc5-3d2f8a1029b0"
}

Comment: Based on the error it seems you are not passing client_id or and client_secret correctly.  Can you please provide the what all parameters you are passing apart from clientid and secret ?

Comment: Hi,I am using client_id,client_secret,username,password,scope,resource and grant_type

Comment: I get this too. I suspect the text "Microsoft.AzureAD.Telemetry.Diagnostics.PII" is being inserted into the error message incorrectly because I'd expect an actual user name instead, and I supplied one. This seems to be an issue with the specification of user credentials. When I remove username and password and choose client_credentials as the grant_type I get a key just fine. That said, I don't have a fix. I just wanted to concur.

Comment: Thanks brit503. Any one can help here?

Comment: Actually I am able to get the token with user created with user id something like xxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com but when we tried with user id which personal email used to send invitation ex:xxx@gmail.com is not working. I have checked for as a member and guest

Comment: @mbr did you solve your problem ? I just run into same issue

Comment: Not actually.i used client credentials to implement  my app further

Answer (score 3):

On my side, I ever encountered this error. For this error, you need to check the user account that you used, the user type must be `member` in your Azure AD tenant, cannot be `guest`.

[image]

Comment: Hi I tried for both guest and member but the result is same.

Comment: The user is in the same tenant with your `xxxx.onmicrosoft.com`?

Comment: Yes in the same tenant